# Kivy app: load only page by page

Tags: android, python, kivy, jsonstore

I'm currently working on a simple Kivy app to try out this library. I'm using a jsonstore to store the input data of a user.

In this app, I'm using some states for the same page. There is a page out front where the state can be set, and for every state there is different information that should be showed on the following pages (where the layout etc. is the same). Now i found that Kivy will load every page on startup, and so it will not load any data from the jsonstore when the state is changed: the data is already loaded for the active state at startup.

Is there a way to use other information out of the store without having to  restart the app after changing the state for these pages?

Comment: Yes you just load the data when entering a screen.

Comment: a topup to what @EL3PHANTEN said, ifu dont know how to do that, call the on_enter function on the Screen.